Problems using a C++ Dll with Excel 2016 32bit
im looking for a solution, that a DLL is not running on Excel 2016 32bit. I've tried so much in the recent weeks, that i have no idea left. I only get it running on Excel 64bit, I have two different DLL's for that. I use Visual Studio 2022, but have also tried it to compile in VB 2017. I'm getting Runtime Error 453 "Cant find entry point in dll". If i use the declatarion with the path "Private Declare Function crypt32 Lib "Path\crypt32.dll" Alias "_crypt32@4" (ByVal inputs As String) As String", i get Runtime error 53 "Cant find file".
Starting with the C++ Code:
C++ 64bit DLL:
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR crypt64(BSTR input) {
    wchar_t output[2]; 
    wchar_t inputChar = input[0];


    if (inputChar >= L'A' && inputChar <= L'Z') {
        inputChar = (inputChar - L'A' + 1) % 26 + L'A'; 
    }
    else if (inputChar >= L'a' && inputChar <= L'z') {
        inputChar = (inputChar - L'a' + 1) % 26 + L'a'; 
    }

    switch (inputChar) {
    case L'a': output[0] = L't'; break;

    default: output[0] = inputChar; break; 
    }

    output[1] = L'\0'; 

    return SysAllocString(output); 
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void FreeBSTR(BSTR bstr) {
    SysFreeString(bstr);
}

C++ 32bit DLL:
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR __stdcall crypt32(BSTR input) {
    wchar_t output[2]; 
    wchar_t inputChar = input[0];


    if (inputChar >= L'A' && inputChar <= L'Z') {
        inputChar = (inputChar - L'A' + 1) % 26 + L'A'; 
    }
    else if (inputChar >= L'a' && inputChar <= L'z') {
        inputChar = (inputChar - L'a' + 1) % 26 + L'a'; 
    }

    switch (inputChar) {
    case L'a': output[0] = L't'; break;

    default: output[0] = inputChar; break; 
    }

    output[1] = L'\0'; 

    return SysAllocString(output); 
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void FreeBSTR(BSTR bstr) {
    SysFreeString(bstr);
}

Its not the whole C++ Code, just testwise to make it work.
VBA Code:
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function crypt64 Lib "crypt64.dll" (ByVal inputs As String) As String
#Else
    Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function crypt32 Lib "crypt32.dll" Alias "_crypt32@4" (ByVal inputs As String) As String
#End If

Sub dllcheck(inputs As String)
    Dim dllPath As String, hModule As Long

    #If Win64 Then
        dllPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Code\crypt64.dll"
    #Else
        dllPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Code\crypt32.dll"
    #End If

    hModule = LoadLibrary(dllPath)
    If hModule = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Connected to DLL"
    End If
End Sub

Sub testconnect()

    Dim result As String

    #If Win64 Then
        dllcheck ""
        result = crypt64("5")
        MsgBox result
    #Else
        dllcheck ""
        result = crypt32("5")
        MsgBox result
    #End If
    
End Sub

Here is my Dumpbin:
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00011055 FreeBSTR
      2    1 00011334 _crypt32@4

Thanks for reviewing.
Tried it without the __stdcall convention, tried to write a Header already, but couldnt get it started. I also used VBA Code that was directly linked to the path (Private Declare Function crypt32 Lib "Path\crypt32.dll" Alias "_crypt32@4" (ByVal inputs As String) As String)

I don't know why you need 2 functions or 2 files. Here's a simplified version.
crypt.cpp (for current content, crypt.c would probably be a better name):
#include <Windows.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>

#define CRYPT_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

CRYPT_EXPORT_API BSTR crypt(const BSTR input);
CRYPT_EXPORT_API void freeBSTR(BSTR bstr);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


BSTR crypt(const BSTR input)
{
    wchar_t output[2]; 
    wchar_t i0 = input[0];

    if ((i0 >= L'A') && (i0 <= L'Z')) {
        i0 = (i0 - L'A' + 1) % 26 + L'A'; 
    } else if ((i0 >= L'a') && (i0 <= L'z')) {
        i0 = (i0 - L'a' + 1) % 26 + L'a'; 
    }

    switch (i0) {
    case L'a':
        output[0] = L't';
        break;
    default:
        output[0] = i0;
        break; 
    }
    output[1] = L'\0'; 
    return SysAllocString(output);
}


void freeBSTR(BSTR bstr)
{
    SysFreeString(bstr);
}

Output (split in 2 parts for clarity):

Build:

[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q079122180]> sopr.bat
### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###

[prompt]>
[prompt]> dir /b
crypt.cpp

[prompt]> :: Configure VS22 for 032bit
[prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86 > nul

[prompt]>
[prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL crypt.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:libcrypt32.dll OleAut32.lib
crypt.cpp
   Creating library libcrypt32.lib and object libcrypt32.exp

[prompt]>
[prompt]> dir /b
crypt.cpp
crypt.obj
libcrypt32.dll
libcrypt32.exp
libcrypt32.lib

[prompt]>
[prompt]> :: Configure VS22 for 064bit
[prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul

[prompt]>
[prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL crypt.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:libcrypt64.dll OleAut32.lib
crypt.cpp
   Creating library libcrypt64.lib and object libcrypt64.exp

[prompt]>
[prompt]> dir /b
crypt.cpp
crypt.obj
libcrypt32.dll
libcrypt32.exp
libcrypt32.lib
libcrypt64.dll
libcrypt64.exp
libcrypt64.lib



Test (same Cmd window):

[prompt]> :: ---------- Check the 064bit .dll ----------
[prompt]> :: Exports
[prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports .\libcrypt64.dll

Dump of file .\libcrypt64.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for libcrypt64.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 crypt
          2    1 00001100 freeBSTR

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .text

[prompt]>
[prompt]> :: Architecture
[prompt]> dumpbin /headers .\libcrypt64.dll | findstr "machine"
            8664 machine (x64)

[prompt]>
[prompt]> :: ---------- Check the 032bit .dll ----------
[prompt]> :: Exports
[prompt]> dumpbin /nologo /exports .\libcrypt32.dll

Dump of file .\libcrypt32.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for libcrypt32.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001000 crypt
          2    1 000010D0 freeBSTR

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        2000 .text

[prompt]>
[prompt]> :: Architecture
[prompt]> dumpbin /headers .\libcrypt32.dll | findstr "machine"
             14C machine (x86)
                   32 bit word machine




Same function name, so the VBA code could be cleaned by that 064bit / 032bit ugliness (only thing that differs is the .dll name).
Check:

[SO]: stdcall name mangling using extern c and dllexport vs module definitions (msvc++)

[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer) (not related, but might be interesting)



You are a genius, i dont know what was wrong with my Code, but you finally helped me after atleast 100 hours of time! Thanks
